# A grid system (Photoshop/Pixelmator) for designing for the iPad

Tags: mobile, ipad, grid

I am designing an iPad app, so I could really use a grid template. I could probably just work with the [960 grid system](http://960.gs/); however, I'd love to find a solution that is tailor-made for the purpose (that is, takes into account such things as the iPad's resolution and suggested (by Xcode's Interface Builder) screen margins). Any suggestions? How do you approach iPad interface design?

Comment: This is more of a User Interface issue than a Graphic Design issue, thus no `ios` tag. Please read the FAQ for more information. Migrating now...

Comment: Are you creating an iOS app or a web site?

Comment: I'm creating an app.

Comment: but is it an native app with native controls or a html5 app with phonegap or something similar?

Comment: It's a native app, and its interface is going to be custom-made (i.e., I am mostly _not_ going to use default iOS interface elements). Thus, I need some sort of a grid to guide me. The simplest example of that: you know how when you use Interface Builder, the software shows gridlines suggesting that you should not put stuff any closer to the edge? Well, I'd like to have a gridline there in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any grid systems for native iOS development. You have to do your own grids in photoshop.

> I am mostly not going to use default iOS interface elements

The most common way of doing your own components is to extend iOS components with your own skins and behaviors.
If you go for full custom components then you extend the [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and build your elements on top of that, but IMHO for most components it is a costly approach, i.e., lot of development work that you need to do yourself.

Also from a ux perpective it is a good practice to follow the [OS UI Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) so it is good to use or extend native components.
I'm not saying you have to do exactly what the guidelines say or to use native components for everything, but it is a good place to start.
Guidelines are recommendations that were tested (at least we hope so) and that users get to know and get accustomed to, they are not unbreakable rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of iPad stencils here: 
http://emilychang.com/2010/03/ipad-templates-and-stencils/

most are in PSD format bit I did not used them myself.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experimenting with grid layouts for the iPad/iPhone and I've started a collection of PSD templates on GitHub. They're intended for web design but they could also work for designing native app comps.

https://github.com/robflaherty/photoshop-grids

Comment: Great work Rob, I was looking for some Ps mobile grids for a while and never found them.